# TextEdit values are passed to another activity but when revisiting next activity values are lost in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

So I've made two textedits. When you click "**submit**" I want to transfer it to another activity as TextView. I've managed to do this, but only problem is that, when I go to another activity and revisit this activity, those textviews that I've changed it with "**submit**" button are lost. It just says "**null**". Can some one help me to fix it. So it can just stay there and not lose it's data. Here's my `java` 1Activity code:

```
public class TwoTeam extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first_name, second_name;
    String name_first, name_second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_team);

        first_name = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.second_name);

    }

    public void submit_button(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TwoTeam.this, Begin.class);{
            name_first = first_name.getText().toString();
            name_second = second_name.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("name1", name_first);
            intent.putExtra("name2", name_second);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is 2Activity code:

```
public class Begin extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView first_name, second_name;
    String name_first, name_second;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.name_first);
        second_name = findViewById(R.id.name_second);

        name_first = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name1");
        first_name.setText(name_first);

        name_second = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name2");
        second_name.setText(name_second);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you call finish() method after startActivity? If you use this method this class will be killed after Begin class started so you lose information on the TwoTeam class.

Comment: Yeah i get the point. But still. Doesn't work

Comment: How do you go back to TwoTeam class?

Comment: Go forward with a button and go back with a back button